# Using summations to find expected values

Tags: summation, expected-value

This question gave me a table with values for $x$ and $y$ below:

[image: Table showing joint and marginal probability distribution, where X represents units sold of first product, and Y the unit sold of the second product]

The question is find $ E(XY)$

Because they are discrete random variables, I got the general form :

$$\ \sum_{y=0}^{2}\sum_{x=0}^{2} xyf(x,y)$$

From this, I struggled with putting values in.

I start by ignoring the outside sum, focusing on just $y$.

$y=0$ I multiply 0 and 0.25. 0.25 being $f(y)$

For $y=1$, I get $1*0.30 = 0.3$

$y=2, 2*0.45 =0.45$

I go to check the mark scheme to make sure I'm on track and the Y summation is completely wrong and they use $x$. Why is this?

Comment: what does comma mean in your summation expression? And I dont understand why we multipled 2*0.45 and found 0.45

Comment: $E(XY)=\sum xyP(x,y)$. Since $xy=0$ if either $x$ or $y$ is zero, you only have four values to sum.